# How much damage would a sting from a jellyfish-like creature deal?

Tags: damage, homebrew, natural-weapon

I'm doing some homebrew for a campaign, and theres a jellyfish-like aquatic creature with stinging tentacles, and I'm not sure how much damage it should deal. My players are new to the game, and pretty low-level at the moment, but as this is sort of a boss fight, I'd like it to be somewhat challenging for them. how should I calculate damage dealt by the tentacles?

Comment: In what game and system? And how big would that creature be?

Comment: What level the party is supposed to be?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Comment: In addition to the game you are playing, we need to know what level the characters are, how many are in the party, and how difficult you want this encounter to be.

Comment: Also, thinking in meta terms of how strong the party is and how dangerous this creature should be for them is necessary here; we can’t just make it “realistic.” Real-life jellyfish stings range from “literally imperceptible” to “excruciating and near-immediately fatal.” So this can be as dangerous as you want it to be, and so we need to know how dangerous that is.

Comment: Do you want a Blue jellyfish (barely stings), Lion's mane jellyfish (stings, leaves a bad rash), Portuguese Man'o'War (victims are in agony and can die), or Australian box jellyfish (He's Dead Jim)?